# Python: Grouping objects together

Tags: python, object, dictionary, tuples, grouping

Let's take the following piece of code, defining arithmetic operator objects (tokens):

```
class Operator:
    def __init__(self, precedence):
        self.precedence = precedence

PLUS = Operator(0)
UPLUS = Operator(10)
MIN = Operator(0)
UMIN = Operator(10)
MULT = Operator(20)
operators = PLUS, UPLUS, MIN, UMIN, MULT
```

I want the operators to be grouped somewhere so I can iterate over them or check membership. Since I'll be adding a lot of others later, I'd like to have to add them in one place only, rather than in two (implementing an operator but forgetting to add it to `operators` could cause subtle bugs). I've tried things like

```
operators = (PLUS = Operator(0), MIN = Operator(0), ...)
```

and similar, but that's obviously not a valid Python statement.

The solution I'm currently using is a `dict` definition:

```
operators = dict(
    PLUS=Operator(0),
    MIN=Operator(0),
    ...
)
```

This works OK, but it means any time I want to work with a single operator, I have to refer to it as e.g. `operators['PLUS']`, rather than the shorter and clearer `PLUS`. Which I can live with, but I'd like to know if a better solution to the problem exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not have Operators add themselves to your group?

```
class Operator:
    all = []
    def __init__(self, precedence):
        self.precedence = precedence
        self.all.append(self)  # Modifies the class variable, as we haven't
                               # introduced an instance variable with that name.

PLUS = Operator(0)
UPLUS = Operator(10)
MIN = Operator(0)
UMIN = Operator(10)
MULT = Operator(20)

# Freeze the collection of Operators
Operator.all = tuple(Operator.all)
```

Of course, this also works with the collection in a module level variable:

```
operators = []

class Operator:
    def __init__(self, precedence):
        self.precedence = precedence
        operators.append(self)

PLUS = Operator(0)
UPLUS = Operator(10)
MIN = Operator(0)
UMIN = Operator(10)
MULT = Operator(20)

# Freeze the collection of Operators
operators = tuple(operators)
```

If an operator must be added to one of several groups, make the collection representing the group to add the operator to a mandatory argument for the initialization of the operator:

```
u_operators = []
non_u_operators = []

class Operator:
    def __init__(self, precedence, group):
        self.precedence = precedence
        group.append(self)

PLUS = Operator(0, non_u_operators)
UPLUS = Operator(10, u_operators)
MIN = Operator(0, non_u_operators)
UMIN = Operator(10, u_operators)
MULT = Operator(20, non_u_operators)

# Freeze the collections of Operators
non_u_operators = tuple(non_u_operators)
u_operators = tuple(u_operators)
```

Comment: I decided to go with this (I liked the Enum solution too, but referencing elements is a little verbose - e.g. `Operators.PLUS.value`). However I ran into a problem, which I'll edit into the OP.

Comment: Never mind, I found the problem in my code. This solution is fine, I just included a check `if group` in `__init__` and forgot empty lists also evaluate to `False` in bool expressions. Changed to `if group is not None` and it now works fine. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

You could use an `Enum`:

```
from enum import Enum

class Operator:
    def __init__(self, precedence):
        self.precedence = precedence

    def __str__(self):
        return "Operator: prec={}".format(self.precedence)

class Operators(Enum):
    PLUS  = Operator(0)
    UPLUS = Operator(10)
    MIN   = Operator(0)
    UMIN  = Operator(10)
    MULT  = Operator(20)

p = Operators.PLUS
print(p)       # Operators.PLUS
print(p.name)  # PLUS
print(p.value) # Operator: prec=0
```

Comment: +1 for enum. It might also be worth mentioning enums can be enumerated (`[op for op in Operators]`) and have fast membership checking (`Operators.PLUS in Operators`)

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like:

```
class Operator:
    def __init__(self, precedence):
        self.precedence = precedence
Operator.PLUS = Operator(0)
Operator.UPLUS = Operator(10)
Operator.MIN = Operator(0)
Operator.UMIN = Operator(10)
Operator.MULT = Operator(20)

[o for o in dir(Operator) if not o.startswith('__')]
```